# Error: Call to undefined method [Vendor]\[Module]\Ui\DataProvider\DriverDataProvider::addField()

Tags: product, uicomponent, magento2.4

I have override product collection for url key filter by below code

File

```
 [Vendor]\[Module]/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml
```

Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <dataSource name="driver_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">[Vendor]\[Module]\Ui\DataProvider\DriverDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">driver_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="add_field" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">999</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">store_id</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="filter_url_params" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="es" xsi:type="string">*</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
</listing>
```

File

```
[Vendor]\[Module]/Ui/DataProvider/DriverDataProvider.php
```

Code

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Ui\DataProvider;

use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider;


/**
 * Class DataProvider
 */
class DriverDataProvider extends DataProvider
{
    protected function prepareUpdateUrl()
    {

        if (!isset($this->data['config']['filter_url_params'])) {
            return;
        }
        foreach ($this->data['config']['filter_url_params'] as $paramName => $paramValue) {
            if ('*' == $paramValue) {
                $paramValue = $this->request->getParam($paramName);
            }
            if ($paramValue) {
                $this->data['config']['update_url'] = sprintf(
                    '%s%s/%s/',
                    $this->data['config']['update_url'],
                    $paramName,
                    $paramValue
                );
                $this->addFilter(
                    $this->filterBuilder->setField($paramName)->setValue($paramValue)->setConditionType('eq')->create()
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it's showing me this error
[image]

Where am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what is your main goal? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to filter product collection by URL param

Comment: but Magento has it already https://i.imgur.com/yogI3cm.jpg? could you give more information?

Comment: I want to filter programmatically product collection by URL parameter(dynamic), I don't want any manual filter